# Mysql Fetch count for last 5 days in date wise and remaining days count in 6th day

Tags: mysql

I have to fetch records for particular month as Count and date as two separate columns in which for last 5 days It should be group by date wise,And for the remaining days the count should be as 6th day Count as shown below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u9dT.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and your query if you have tried

Comment: @ksl123 : Please find sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07df63/2

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07df63/52
check this

Comment: Thanks..Got it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 queries:
1st query: (fetch for 5 days using group by)
union
2nd query: (fetch rest of data using case statement).